# Markers for advised methods in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, annotations, aop

In a project we use annotions to define aspects.

Unfortunately I can't get eclipse to show a marker next to the advised methods.

In another project we use XML to define the aspects and eclipse shows markers.

Best I post some code to clarify:

First a bean to be advised:

```
package aop.test;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class Worker {
    public void work() {}
}
```

Then the aspect:

```
package aop.test;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Aspect
@Service
public class WorkerLogger {
    @Before("execution(void aop.test.Worker.work())")
    public void log() {
        System.out.println("working...");
    }
}
```

And finally a main method to prepare the ApplicationContext, get the bean and run the advised method:

```
package aop.test;

import org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context;
        context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        context.register(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.class);
        context.scan("aop.test");
        context.refresh();

        context.getBean(Worker.class).work();
    }
}
```

I tried this in eclipse using the STS plugin and the STS itself. I never get a red arrow next to `work()` indicating it is advised.

What am I missing?

Comment: I changed the example to use an XML defining the beans for the worker and the logger, the aspect and `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>` and still see no marker at the advised method. Is there some option I have to enable?

Comment: When I enable Spring Aspects Tooling it just adds the AspectJ Nature and I can see the markers, but the AspectJ Nature is not what I want. Unmanaged instances or static methods are advised as well meaning the AspectJ compiler is used.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the STS plugin on your Eclipse? It should be available on the `Help` > `Eclipse Marketplace`

Comment: I wasn't aware that you could get the whole STS functionality as a plugin for 'regular' eclipse. Thanks for that. Unfortunately neither way do I get the red arrow marker.